# Cannot add import androidx.compose.navigation.NavHostController

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a KMP app and I'm trying to add a second desktop screen. The app with the following imports:

```
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import kotlinx.datetime.Clock
import kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime
import kotlinx.datetime.TimeZone
import kotlinx.datetime.toLocalDateTime
import org.jetbrains.compose.resources.ExperimentalResourceApi
import org.jetbrains.compose.resources.painterResource

import androidx.compose.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.compose.navigation.composeNavHost


import pellettracker.composeapp.generated.resources.Res
import pellettracker.composeapp.generated.resources.compose_multiplatform
```

The import androidx.compose.navigation.NavHostController and the line that follows show in red (error).

My build.gradle.kts file looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
id("io.realm.kotlin") version "1.11.0"
}

kotlin {
androidTarget {
    compilations.all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}

jvm("desktop")

sourceSets {
    val desktopMain by getting
    
    androidMain.dependencies {
        implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
        implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    }
    commonMain.dependencies {
        implementation(compose.runtime)
        implementation(compose.foundation)
        implementation(compose.material)
        implementation(compose.ui)
        implementation(compose.components.resources)
        implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
        implementation(libs.kotlinx.datetime)
        implementation(libs.library.base)
        implementation(libs.library.sync) // If using Device Sync
        implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core) // If using coroutines with the SDK

    }
    desktopMain.dependencies {
        implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
    }
}
}

android {
namespace = "org.ohw.pellettracker"
compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "org.ohw.pellettracker"
    minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
    targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
}
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

dependencies {
    debugImplementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling)
    compileOnly(libs.library.base)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
}
}

compose.desktop {
application {
    mainClass = "MainKt"

    nativeDistributions {
        targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
        packageName = "org.ohw.pellettracker"
        packageVersion = "1.0.0"
    }
}
}
```

From the documentation I've read, only the two lines for implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.runtime.ktx) and
implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
should be needed. Is there something else though that I'm missing?

I've tried syncing, restarting, etc. Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: What *is* the error, though?

Comment: I believe androidx.navigation is not available for multiplatform projects (only for android)
You can use other multiplatform compatible navigation libraries available like [Decompose](https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose) or [Voyager](https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager)

Answer (score 1):

The error was "Unresolved reference: navigation"

It looks like M Ashhal is correct. I'll switch to Decompose or Voyager.